# Bot running error in discord.js (Error: Cannot find module / code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [])

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I recently switched from discord.py to discord.js and i am having an error when i try to run the bot

I've watched a lot of tutorials and tried all the different ways I've found to import the library into VS Code but they all give some error

What I'm trying to do now is this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

require('dotenv').config()

var prefix = '?'
var newprefix = ''

    client.on('ready', () =>
    {
        console.log('Online')
    })
```

And im getting this error when i type "node main.js":

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop\Bots\JSBot\main.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)   
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

I believe I have downloaded the library and other dependencies correctly, but even if I try other methods some different error always comes up.

What would I be doing wrong?

Comment: Send a screen of your directory please.

Comment: Are you sure you named your file `main.js` and not `index.js` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in that the file you're trying to run is not existent in the current directory. Ensure that your primary file is named `main.js` and that your terminals directory is set to the directory which includes `main.js` while running `node main.js`